# Create View unable to find success url to redirect to

Tags: python, django

I am a Django developer with a quick question. I have the following code in which I have created a model 'Plan', which has several fields and I have also created a view for it. However, when I submit the form for the create view, I get an error saying that it could not find a url to redirect to. I have tried adding the 'get_absolute_url' method to the model and I have also tried adding the 'success_url' attribute to the create view, but I always get the following error: `The view work.views.PlansCreateView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead`

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

date = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=10)

class Plan(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_deadline = models.DateTimeField(default=date)
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.supervisor.username} {self.title}"
```

**Project Urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Core
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name="core-home"),
    path('about/', AboutView.as_view(), name="core-about"),
    # Users
    path('register/', register, name="users-register"),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name="users/login.html"), name="users-login"),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(template_name="users/logout.html"), name="users-logout"),
    # Work
    path('plans/', PlansListView.as_view(), name="work-plans"),
    path('<int:pk>/tasks', TasksListView.as_view(), name="work-tasks"),
    path('plans/create/', PlansCreateView.as_view(), name="work-plans-create")
]
```

**Template for Create View**

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

    <div class="work-plans-create">

        <form method="POST" action="">

            {% csrf_token %}

            <h2>Plan</h2>
            
            {{ form|crispy }}

            <button type="submit" class="button-filled">Create Plan</button>

        </form>

    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

**Create View**

```
class PlansCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Plan
    fields = ["title", "description", "date_deadline"]
    template_name = "work/plans_forms.html"
    success_url = 'work-plans/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.supervisor = self.request.user
        super().form_valid(form)
```

My objective is to redirect to the url named 'work-plans' (check the urls.py file).
Thank you everyone in advance.

P.S. I know there are similar questions to this one already on the stack but they did not solve my problem.

P.S.S The 'plans' are being created successfully (I looked at the admin page). The only problem is that it doesn't know where to redirect to.

Answer (score 1):

Use a reverse on the URL by name;

```py
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


class PlansCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Plan
    fields = ["title", "description", "date_deadline"]
    template_name = "work/plans_forms.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("work-plans")
```

This will make django lookup the URL from your URL patterns.

Comment: Thanks so much markwalker. This solved my problem. Another quick question - what's the difference between reverse and reverse_lazy.

Comment: You'd use the lazy version because it's a class attribute. You can read the docs on it here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy

Answer (score 1):

To fix this error `The view work.views.PlansCreateView didn't return an HttpResponse object` you need to return from `form_valid` method.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
   form.instance.supervisor = self.request.user
   return super().form_valid(form)
```

Also, your `success_url` parameter is wrong, see @markwalker_'s answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch May.D. This also solved my problem. Again, thanks.